# Writing to Registry "RegSetValueEx" only working wile debugging

Tags: debugging, api, vb6, registry

I am trying to modify specific registry keys, but it will only work when I debug the application not after I build it.

I find this very weird so I am turning to you guys for help.

```
Private Declare Function RegSetValueEx Lib "advapi32.dll" Alias "RegSetValueExA" (ByVal       hKey As Long, ByVal lpValueName As String, ByVal Reserved As Long, ByVal dwType As Long, lpData As Any, ByVal cbData As Long) As Long
Private Declare Function RegOpenKeyEx Lib "advapi32.dll" Alias "RegOpenKeyExA" (ByVal hKey As Long, ByVal lpSubKey As String, ByVal ulOptions As Long, ByVal samDesired As Long, phkResult As Long) As Long
Private Const BM_CLICK = &HF5
Const REG_DWORD = 4
Const HKEY_CURRENT_USER = &H80000001
Const HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE = &H80000002
Const REGKEY = "Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\system"
Const KEY_WRITE = &H20006
Dim Path As Long
Dim Value As Long

Sub TASK()
On Error GoTo hell:
Value = 1
If RegOpenKeyEx(HKEY_CURRENT_USER, REGKEY, 0, KEY_WRITE, Path) Then Exit Sub

RegSetValueEx Path, NameOfKey, 0, REG_DWORD, Value, Len(Value)
Exit Sub
hell:
MsgBox Err & Error(Err)
End Sub

Sub UAC()
On Error GoTo hell:
Value = 0
If RegOpenKeyEx(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, REGKEY, 0, KEY_WRITE, Path) Then Exit Sub

RegSetValueEx Path, "ConsentPromptBehaviorAdmin", 0&, REG_DWORD, Value, Len(Value)
Exit Sub
hell:
MsgBox Err & Error(Err)
End Sub
```

I am sure it is just something very small that I am missing.

Comment: What operating system are you using?  (Is the problem unelevated elevated user in vista/7)?

Comment: We need more information.  Are you running on the same machine in debug vs. compiled?  The same user account?  Which write or open is failing is failing?  The calls to `RegOpenKeyEx` and `RegSetValueEx` will return an error code describing the error if they fail.  You should record that and possibly display it in a message box so you actually know what's failing and why.

Comment: It's unlikely that you would have write permission to a key named `Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\system`. The `Microsoft\Windows` part is a dead-giveaway that it doesn't belong to your app.

Comment: I am using the same machine with the debug and the compiled versions yes. I am admin so i see no reason for elevated user error's being that it is working in debug. I have tried to catch the error's on run time in message boxes various different ways and i get none, that is what is adding to my confusion. However, i am sure that the "RegSetValueEx" call is the one failing because it is passing through the if with no problems. If anymore information is needed let me know please, i really appreciate the effort so far in helping me troubleshoot the problem.

Comment: I can edit it manually so i see no reason why an app wouldn't be able to.

Comment: If you right click the compiled EXE and Run as Administrator, does it still fail?

Answer (score 2):

This may not solve all your issues, but it is something important to consider:

```
If RegOpenKeyEx(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, REGKEY, 0, KEY_WRITE, Path) Then Exit Sub
```

You cannot write to HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE unless you are an Administrator.  In XP this will throw an error and fail, I believe.  I believe that Vista and Win7 handle this differently.  I think in Vista and Win7 the write is virtualized in the user's profile and no error is thrown.  The entry is stored not in HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE but in what is called the Virtual Store.  These versions of Windows also can virtualized file access to protected system files through this service.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa965884(v=vs.85).aspx

also #6 in this article...
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/chinmay_palei/archive/2011/01/16/windows-7-application-compatibility-issues-fix-centre.aspx

Is it possible that you have set your VB IDE to run as Administrator?  This would cause your debug session to run as Admin, but when you are running the EXE on it's own it would run as user?  Either way, this line will definately cause errors for your users.